ModuleNotFoundError at /accounts/login/ No module named 'allauth.forms'
Iam trying to add allauth login and signup in my project and getting this error
*ModuleNotFoundError at /accounts/login/*
*No module named 'allauth.forms'*
This is the traceback
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/decorators.py", line 12, in wrap
    resp = function(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 143, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 80, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 84, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/account/mixins.py", line 40, in dispatch
    response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 143, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/account/mixins.py", line 59, in get
    response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 142, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 102, in get_context_data
    ret = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/account/mixins.py", line 122, in get_context_data
    ret = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 72, in get_context_data
    kwargs["form"] = self.get_form()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/account/mixins.py", line 79, in get_form
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 36, in get_form
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 92, in get_form_class
    return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, "login", self.form_class)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/utils.py", line 304, in get_form_class
    form_class = import_attribute(form_class)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/utils.py", line 145, in import_attribute
    ret = getattr(importlib.import_module(pkg), attr)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.forms'

`
these are the full codes
*forms.py*
`
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm,SignupForm
from django import forms



class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Customize the form initialization if needed

    def clean_custom_field(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        # Add custom validation for the field if needed
        return username

    def login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Perform the login and any additional actions
        return super(CustomLoginForm, self).login(*args, **kwargs)
        
class CustomSignUpForm(SignupForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True)

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(CustomSignUpForm, self).save(request)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.save()
        return user


`
*project urls.py*
I made a seperate app called accounts for whole authorization processes
`
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('consultation.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('allauth.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    path('dashboard',include('dashboard.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
     document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

`
*app urls.py*
`
"""
URL configuration for Hospital_Management project.

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.urls import path
from .views import CustomSignUpView,CustomLoginView

app_name ='user'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/',CustomSignUpView.as_view(),name='account_signup'),
    path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='account_login'),
]

`
*views.py*
`
from django.shortcuts import render
from allauth.account.views import LoginView,SignupView
from .forms import CustomSignUpForm, CustomLoginForm

# Create your views here.
class CustomSignUpView(SignupView):
    form_class = CustomSignUpForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['username'] = CustomSignUpForm.username
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        # Add any custom behavior after the form is valid
        return response
    
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['username'] = CustomLoginForm.username  # Add any extra context you need
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        # Add any custom behavior after the form is valid
        return response

`
I've copied this form chat gpt since the allauth documentation is confusing , please got through these and help me what is wrong with the code

Did you configure this package for use in your settings.py? https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/installation/quickstart.html

i configured the allauth and accounts app...
